# How to pass json data which is sourced from ajax post request via a service into jQuery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I have an asp.net webforms appication in it I have an HTML table which is getting populated via ajax call sourced by a service, I want to convert the table into jQuery DataTable and source the data to the datatable but couldn't get it done and over click it is throwing 2 errors in alert (1) is "DataTables warning: table id=tblnotificationlogHistory - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/7"](http://datatables.net/tn/7%22)  and (2) is "DataTables warning: table id=tblnotificationlogHistory - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/3"](http://datatables.net/tn/3%22).

Aspx Html Code:

```
    <table id="tblnotificationlogHistory" class="tblnotificationlogHistory table table-bordered"
                                            style="margin: 10px auto; width: 90%;">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Date
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th class='mainCol'>
                                                        Status
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        Updated By
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                        </table>
    
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-header-repeat">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="additionalcomments" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"comments") %>'
                                                        CssClass="commentsHistory"></asp:Label>

JS Code:
```

```
jQuery(".statusname, .commentsHistory").click(function (event) {
                    debugger;
                    var callForCommHistory = (jQuery(this).attr("class") == 'commentsHistory');
                    var ccrsflattenId = jQuery(this).next('._ccrsflattenId').text();
                    var FlattenExtID = jQuery(this).next('._ccrsflattenId').next('._FlattenExtID').text();
                    var webMethod = '/Service/CRService.asmx/GetUnmatchedHistoryStatuses'
                    var parameters = "{ccrsflattenId: " + ccrsflattenId + " , FlattenExtID: " + FlattenExtID + " , isCallForCommHistory: " + callForCommHistory + "}";
                    console.log('parameters: ' + parameters);
                    showLoader();
                    jQuery.noConflict();
                    jQuery(".tblnotificationlogHistory").DataTable({
                        paging: false,
                        searching: false,
                        info: false,
                        processing: true,
                        serverside: true,
                        "ajax": {
                        "type": "POST",
                        "url":  "webMethod",
                        "data": "parameters",
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "dataType" : "json"
                        },
 "columns": [
                    { "data": "createdDate" },
                    { "data": "comments" },
                    { "data": "updatedby" }
                    ]
                    });
                });
```

/Service/CRService.asmx/GetUnmatchedHistoryStatuses Service Code:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
            public string GetUnmatchedHistoryStatuses(string ccrsflattenId, string FlattenExtID, bool isCallForCommHistory = true)
            {
                string daresult = string.Empty;
                try
                {
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                    SqlParameterCollection sqlParameterCollection = ClientSessions.GetParameterCollectionConstructor();
    
                    sqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue("@isCommHistory", isCallForCommHistory);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FlattenExtID))
                        sqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue("@rqFlattenExtID", Convert.ToInt32(FlattenExtID));
    
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccrsflattenId))
                        sqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue("@ccrsFlattenExtID", Convert.ToInt32(ccrsflattenId));
    
                    dataSet = CommissionHandler.GetUnmatchedHistory_Statuses(sqlParameterCollection);
    
                    if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
    
                        daresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                return daresult;
            }

Csharp code to hit the stored procedure with parameters passed with the ajax call:
```

```
public static DataSet GetUnmatchedHistory_Statuses(SqlParameterCollection collection)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ClientSessions.ConnectionString, "CR_GetUnmatchedHistory_Statuses", collection);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            if (ds.Tables.Count < 1)
                ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable());

            return ds;
        }
```

Comment: The first error indicates that ajax request receive an error response from your server (a response other then 200), while second error tells that your code is trying to modify option after datatable initialization. this link could help: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/

Answer (score 1):

Hi It looks like the formatting in your DataTable Init is incorrect , it should be something like :

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/data-source',
        type: 'POST'
    }
} );
```

You have ajax in quotes and your url and data are quoted therefore they will not refer to the JS vars..

i.e.

```
 jQuery(".tblnotificationlogHistory").DataTable({
                        paging: false,
                        searching: false,
                        info: false,
                        processing: true,
                        serverside: true,
                        ajax: {
                        type: POST,
                        url:  webMethod,
                        data: parameters,
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType : 'json'
                        },
```

Comment: Removing quotations did not completely resolve it. Still the data is not populating in the datatable and on click can not reinitialize datatable error is popping up.

Comment: You will need to switch on your Dev tools in the browser and inspect the JSON returned from you call to the server for data. It might be an idea to include your full code also as from above it is not apparent what onclick events you may have i.e. "and on click can not reinitialize datatable error is popping up" what is meant to happen when you click ?

Comment: I have edited the question with code.. please check

Comment: Can you inspect your Browser Dev Tools console and see if the call for the JSON data is actually occurring and if so what data is returned ?